# SELECT users with at least 2 identical products

Tags: sql, postgresql

Users table:

```
user_id name
1 john
2 mark
3 scott
4 piter
```

user_products table:

```
user_id product_id
1 2
1 4
1 5
2 4
2 5
2 7
3 1
3 5
3 4
3 2
4 1
```

As we see, users 1,2,3 all have products 4 and 5. So how to select users with at least 2 identical products ?

Comment: You can find  *pairs* of users that share at least 2 products. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a self join:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.name
FROM user_products up1
INNER JOIN user_products up2
    ON up1.product_id = up2.product_id AND
       up1.user_id <> up2.user_id
INNER JOIN Users u
    ON up1.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY
    u.user_id,
    u.name
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT up1.product_id) > 1;
```

### Demo

The idea here is to try to match each of the records for a given user to records from a different user, but having the same product.  The aggregation step then checks if a given user still has at least two products after the inner join, which implies that in fact he does have at least two products in common with some other user.

The matching users here are: john, mark, and scott

Comment: it takes too long on big table. I have indexes on all fields. Is there another way to write it?

Comment: `I have indexes on all fields` ... but that doesn't mean that they indices are optimal, or even that Postgres is using any of them.  You should edit your question and tell us which indices you have.

Comment: An index on `(product_id, user_id)` on the `user_products` table might help, assuming Postgres chooses to use it.  Aggregation queries tend to take up resources, so expect some time to run this for a very large table.

Comment: I said it wrong. No indexes on all fields, but required indexes. I analized query with explain. There are about 100 thousands records in users table. And 600 thousands in products. I aborted query, because it took too long

Comment: `but required indexes` ... _what_ indexes?  Can you show us?

Comment: I have users.user_id as primary key. And index on (produc_id, user_id)

Comment: Then I don't have any other ideas on how to improve performance.  You might want to look into using alternative data stores, such as GraphQL, which are designed to work with networks/relationships such as your data.

Answer (score 0):

A self join is the right approach, but I think the right logic is:

```
SELECT up1.user_id, up2.user_id
FROM user_products up1 JOIN
     user_products up2
     ON up1.product_id = up2.product_id AND
        up1.user_id < up2.user_id
GROUP BY up1.user_id, up2.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT up1.product_id) >= 2;
```

If you want the list of products, you can include `array_agg(distinct up1.product_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
select distinct b.user_id from #UserProduct b
join (
select count(1) cnt,product_id from #UserProduct
group by product_id
having count(1) = 3)  c
on b.product_id=c.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This time, I hope can help you

```
Select * into #User From (
    Select '1' [user_id], 'john' [user_name] Union All
    Select '2' [user_id], 'mark' [user_name] Union All
    Select '3' [user_id], 'scott' [user_name] Union All
    Select '4' [user_id], 'piter' [user_name] 
) A

Select * into #UserProduct From (
    Select '1' [user_id],  '2' [product_id] union All
    Select '1' [user_id],  '4' [product_id] union All
    Select '1' [user_id],  '5' [product_id] union All
    Select '2' [user_id],  '4' [product_id] union All
    Select '2' [user_id],  '5' [product_id] union All
    Select '2' [user_id],  '7' [product_id] union All
    Select '3' [user_id],  '1' [product_id] union All
    Select '3' [user_id],  '5' [product_id] union All
    Select '3' [user_id],  '4' [product_id] union All
    Select '3' [user_id],  '2' [product_id] union All
    Select '4' [user_id],  '1' [product_id] 
) A

Select U1.[user_id] From (
    Select 
        A.[Product_id] Product_id1, 
        B.[Product_id] Product_id2
    From (
        Select [Product_id] From #UserProduct
        Group By [Product_id]
    ) A
    Left Join (
        Select [Product_id] From #UserProduct
        Group By [Product_id]
    ) B On 1 = 1
    Where A.[Product_id] < B.[Product_id]
) Product2
Left Join (
    Select [user_id] From #UserProduct 
    Group By [user_id]
) [User] On 1 = 1
Left Join #UserProduct U1 On U1.[user_id] = [User].[user_id] and U1.Product_id = Product_id1
Left Join #UserProduct U2 On U2.[user_id] = [User].[user_id] and U2.Product_id = Product_id2
Where (U1.[user_id] Is Not Null And U2.[user_id] Is Not Null)
Group By U1.[user_id]
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hope can help you

```
Select * into #User From (
    Select '1' [user_id], 'john' [user_name] Union All
    Select '2' [user_id], 'mark' [user_name] Union All
    Select '3' [user_id], 'scott' [user_name] Union All
    Select '4' [user_id], 'piter' [user_name] 
) A

Select * into #UserProduct From (
    Select '1' [user_id],  '2' [product_id] union All
    Select '1' [user_id],  '4' [product_id] union All
    Select '1' [user_id],  '5' [product_id] union All
    Select '2' [user_id],  '4' [product_id] union All
    Select '2' [user_id],  '5' [product_id] union All
    Select '2' [user_id],  '7' [product_id] union All
    Select '3' [user_id],  '1' [product_id] union All
    Select '3' [user_id],  '5' [product_id] union All
    Select '3' [user_id],  '4' [product_id] union All
    Select '3' [user_id],  '2' [product_id] union All
    Select '4' [user_id],  '1' [product_id] 
) A


Select U.[user_id], U.[user_name], P.[qty_product]
From #User U
Left Join (
    Select 
        [user_id], Count(*) [qty_product] 
    From #UserProduct
    Group By [user_id]
    Having Count(*) > 1
) P On P.[user_id] = U.[user_id]
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: This returns all users which have more than one product, not users who have two or more products in common with other users.

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: Apparently so did I `:-)`